# Python BS4 - Write to JSON using a variable as key & value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I am working on a little web scraping project and I am trying to iterate through a table. Then putting the left side (tr) of the table as the key, and right side (td) of the table as the value of that key into a JSON file. It is working somewhat, meaning that it writes the correct key/value. But it only writes the last cell in the table.

I have tried to write to the JSON file in a few different ways and I found a few posts on google about it but got nothing to work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, ensure_ascii=True)

path = './'
fileName = 'test'
data = {}

r = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-mpg-b550-gaming-carbon-wifi/p/N82E16813144322')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

tables = soup.findAll("table", class_='table-horizontal')
for x in range(len(tables)):
    for tr, td in zip(soup.findAll('table', class_='table-horizontal')[x].findAll('th'), soup.findAll('table', class_='table-horizontal')[x].findAll('td')):
        tr_item = tr.text
        td_item = td.text
        data["chassi"] = []
        data["chassi"].append({
            tr_item: td_item
        })

        writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data)
```

I am trying to iterate through the `specs` of [this](https://www.newegg.com/msi-mpg-b550-gaming-carbon-wifi/p/N82E16813144322) website.

EDIT:
This is the result I am getting in my JSON file:

```
{ "chassi": [{ "Date First Available ": "June 15, 2020" }] }
```

Comment: Why do you have the call to `writeToJSONFile` inside your loops? Move that outside your loops.

Comment: I give answer please check. It's working. You need to define your dict outside of `for loop`. Every time your dict initialize and you need to call  `writeToJSONFile` outside of `for loop`.

Comment: And also i add if no data are present then no file was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, ensure_ascii=True)

path = './'
fileName = 'test'
data = {}

r = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-mpg-b550-gaming-carbon-wifi/p/N82E16813144322')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data["chassi"] = []
tables = soup.findAll("table", class_='table-horizontal')
for x in range(len(tables)):    
    for tr, td in zip(soup.findAll('table', class_='table-horizontal')[x].findAll('th'), soup.findAll('table', class_='table-horizontal')[x].findAll('td')):
        tr_item = tr.text
        td_item = td.text
        
        data["chassi"].append({
            tr_item: td_item
        })

if len(data["chassi"]) > 0:
    writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get something to look like this? https://pastebin.com/HWzEtnqL - Probably deserves a new post itself, but I am guessing the `data["chassi"].append({})` is what is the cause for it to look like this: https://pastebin.com/iyRZDLie

Comment: @simonsjöö yes possible give me 10 minutes I will do for you.

Comment: @simonsjöö just change `data["chassi"].append({tr_item: td_item})` to `data["chassi"][tr_item] = td_item`. and `data["chassi"] = []` to `data["chassi"] = {]`.
  let me know if it's work?

Comment: yeah, that fixed it. Thank you :)